# filter specific text from file?

Tags: text-processing

I've got a couple of textfiles containing mails,usernames, passwords and emails in various formats.

Could someone help me to filter out the content I don't need?

For example, this Is one line of textfile1: `('RandomUserName','usernamehashhashhashahashshsas',0.000000000,0),`

How can I filter away everything but the hash???

Number two: `randomuser:hashashashashashashashashash:usermail@mail.com:\`

Again, how can i filter out/remove everything but the hash, and remove the "\" at the end of each hash?

Comment: Exactly what would the expected output be from the input?

Comment: @thrig I don't see the issue. The OP did say what they wanted.

Comment: @roaima not really, is that first username part of the hash, or not? Is for "hashash" the whole thing matched, or exactly only `hash`? Same deal for the trailing "shsas" string, is that to be excluded, or is it something different? If they can't clarify their requirements...

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of handling this. The easiest is probably `cut`, which will do most of what you want straight off.

```
('RandomUserName','usernamehashhashhashahashshsas',0.000000000,0),
```

You can process this with a two command pipeline, which says to pick out the second comma-separated field from each line, and then delete single quotes from the result:

```
cut -d, -f2 datafile | tr -d "'"
```

The second part is easier as there are no quotes to remove.

```
randomuser:hashashashashashashashashash:usermail@mail.com:\
```

A single command will be sufficient here:

```
cut -d: -f2 datafile
```

Comment: thank you!! Works, kinda.. the problem is that my file has ~5k rows which are identical to the ones i posted `('RandomUserName','...´ but terminal just filters and outputs the first two lines in my file, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @diddlydope you are probably using a file with Windows line endings. Try running `sed 's/\r//g' file > newfile` and then using `newfile` instead.

Comment: I tried, but got the same results.. Just the two first lines shows as output

Comment: @diddlydope what type of system created these files? For both files please post the output of `wc -l <datafile`, where `datafile` is the file name.